# Difference between Bit and Boolean datatypes in PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql, sqldatatypes

I am new to PostgreSQL. I have doubt while creating table in the database. Can anyone clarify me the difference between `bit` and `boolean` datatypes?

Comment: Many posts on this subject. You can google your title and you'll find some answers. Answer for other RDBMS should be just as good as for postgreSQL

Answer (score 38):

A `bit` only stores the numbers `0` and `1` (or `null`).

A `boolean` only stores `true` and `false` (or `null`). A number (0, 1) is **not** a boolean. A boolean value can be used anywhere a boolean *expression* is expected. So you can e.g. do this:

```
where is_active
```

A bit column needs to be compared to something:

```
where a_bit_column = 0
```

(the result of `a_bit_column = 0` is a boolean)

---

Contrary to the what some DBMS think, the expression `where 0` or `where 1` is **not** valid boolean expression.

Comment: since, I'm new learning postgres, can you share in what situation we should use bit over boolean? any caveats?

Comment: @mehul9595 Postgres Hero Erwin with another great answer: https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/156851/49113

Comment: +1 to "...the expression `where 0`..." is not a valid Boolean expression. I am learning Postgres myself right now and seeing a lot of unsavory practices.