# How to save a boolean in a bit(1) field

Tags: java, postgresql, hibernate

I have a code that reads and writes into a table, which has a field of bit(1). When I am reading this table hibernate converts this into `boolean` just fine but when I try to save to it, it gives me `column is type bit but expression is type boolean`. I ca not change this field to `boolean`.

So far I tried seeling `@Type` to hibernate's `BooleanType` but no avail.

Comment: How exactly is your entity declaring this field/column? Normally a `@Column (name= "thecolumnsname") protected Boolean myBoolean;` should suffice.

Comment: Exactly like that. It works when I read values from table but only throws this when I try to write to the table.

Comment: Well I heard that Hibernate has problems mapping boolean and bits, but normally if you can *read* a `bit(1)` as `Boolean` then you should be able to *write* the `Boolean` as `bit(1)` - especially since there is no equivalent in Java to `bit`. However, you could try a different JavaType (mabye byte or short) and see if your database understands how to convert `1 :: short`  to `1 :: bit`. If this is possible, then you could implement your own [converter](https://thoughts-on-java.org/hibernate-enum-mappings/)

Comment: Why are you using a `bit` to a boolean? That columns should be defined as `boolean`

Answer (score 0):

From [the documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/datatype.html).

> bit [ (n) ]       fixed-length bit string

While in some databases (MySQL and some others) `bit(1)` **is** a `boolean`, in Postgres [it's not](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46072700/difference-between-bit-and-boolean-datatypes-in-postgresql). Postgres has the `boolean` datatype that should be used.

Comment: Since I cannot change to boolean on postgresql, how can I represent a bit string in java/hibernate?

Comment: With a custom `UserType` at least, but I would try my hardest to use the correct datatype in the db. Why can't you change it?

Comment: Well I asked people who used it and they say there is a ton of code that uses it and they would have to change that code if they changed it.

Comment: Code as in Java code or stored procedures (or other such things)? Because if you're using it as a boolean everywhere, then actually **making** it a `boolean` wouldn't require (at least too many) changes. Unless there's code that actually requires it to be a `bit`.

Comment: As in 12-year-old-C++-code that no one cared to properly maintain and that grew into a brilliant example of how not to write an application. Believe me I cannot change anything on DB side :(

Comment: @bobku123 what hibernate dialect are you using? If the datatype is `bit` (or `bit(1)`) it should actually work as is, and if it works when reading, that's a "bit" suspect. What exception do you get when trying to write the boolean?

Comment: I am using postgreSQLDialect. I get "org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper logExceptions, ERROR: ERROR: column ".." is of type bit but expression is of type boolean"

Comment: @bobku123 edit your question and include the full stacktrace, including the query being performed. It might be an issue with the query, and not the boolean mapping.

Comment: Actually MySQL does not treat "bit as a boolean". MySQL treats everything as a boolean - if a value can be converted to a number value greater than 0 it's considered "true", otherwise false. `1thing` is considered `true`

Answer (score 0):

you have assign (byte) 0 / (byte) 1 .It will support to convert boolean to byte. and byte to boolean.